# Not sure I quite understand variable scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this seems a bit easy. I'm still relatively new to Javascript.

I am generating a list of checkboxes. On the **onClick** of a **checkbox**, i want to make it pop up its associated text. ie. Checkbox named "one" should then display "one". In my example it only displays "two".

However the click() callback method only ever calls the text of the last added checkbox. Does the 'v' variable in here not get assigned per checkbox? It seems like the'v' is behaving like a global variable.

```
this.view = document.createElement("div");

var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
var popupValues = {"A", "B"};
for (var i=0;i<this.popupValues.length;i++) {
    var v = popupValues[i];

    var tr  = document.createElement('tr');
    var tdCheck  = document.createElement('td');

    var ChkBx = document.createElement('input')

    ChkBx.type = 'checkbox';

    tdCheck.appendChild(ChkBx);

    var self = this;

    $(ChkBx).live('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){

            alert('checked' + v);
        } else {
            alert('un-checked' + v);
        }
    });


    var td  = document.createElement("td");


    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('' + v));
    tr.appendChild(tdCheck);
    tr.appendChild(td);


    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

table.appendChild(tbody);

document.appendChild(table)
```

Here is jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/n5GZW/2/

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: updated JSFiddle

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt do anything...

Comment: you sure? I am using Chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/n5GZW/1/

Comment: you haven't enabled jQuery in the fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n5GZW/2/

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery to create the elements?

Comment: When your event handler runs, it runs with value of v at that very time. So naturally it's the value that you left it as (the last). Cheers.

Comment: @Alnitak I did. Still showing a black page in the result window.

Comment: sorry. copied the wrong link

Comment: try now http://jsfiddle.net/n5GZW/2/

Comment: You'd do good to read [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
   var table = document.createElement("table");
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");


var popupValues = [
    "one", "two"
];

for (var i = 0; i < popupValues.length; i++) {

    var v = popupValues[i];

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var tdCheck = document.createElement('td');

    var ChkBx = document.createElement('input');
    ChkBx.type = 'checkbox';
    ChkBx.value=v;
    tdCheck.appendChild(ChkBx);

    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('' + v));
    tr.appendChild(tdCheck);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    tbody.appendChild(tr);


    var self = this;

    $(ChkBx).click('change', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('check ' + $(this).val());
        } else {
            alert('un-checked');
        }
    });

}

table.appendChild(tbody);
document.body.appendChild(table)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5GZW/4/
add `ChkBx.value=v;` to get value like `$(this).val()` on click

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it only avoids the use of the variable.

Answer (score 3):

> "Does the 'v' variable in here not get assigned per checkbox?"

Well, it's assigned, but not declared for each checkbox.

In Javascript variables only have function scope. Even if you try to create a new variable in each iteration of the loop, it's only a single variable declared at the function level, shared by all iterations. The declaration is hoisted to the function level, only the assignment happens inside the loop.

You can use an immediatey executed function expression to create another scope inside the loop, where you can create a new variable for each iteration:

```
for (var i=0;i<this.popupValues.length;i++) {
  (function(v){
    // code of the loop goes in here
    // v is a new variable for each iteration
  }(popupValues[i]));
}
```

Comment: i think i understand. I think i got mislead because I assume a local variable is just local. But relative to an inner method, it is kinda global i guess

Answer (score 2):

You could've searched in SO for `event binding in for loop`.

Here is one solution:

Try this:

```
this.view = document.createElement("div");

var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
var popupValues = {"A", "B"};
for (var i=0;i<this.popupValues.length;i++) {
    var v = popupValues[i];

    var tr  = document.createElement('tr');
    var tdCheck  = document.createElement('td');

    var ChkBx = document.createElement('input')

    ChkBx.type = 'checkbox';

    tdCheck.appendChild(ChkBx);

    var self = this;

    (function(val) {
      $(ChkBx).on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){

            alert('checked' + val);
        } else {
            alert('un-checked' + val);
        }
      });
    })(v);


    var td  = document.createElement("td");


    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('' + v));
    tr.appendChild(tdCheck);
    tr.appendChild(td);


    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

table.appendChild(tbody);

document.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: @oliverwatkins should keep in mind that `.live` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and was removed in 1.9

Comment: @EduardGamonal: yes, I know that. My browser got crashed for some other OS, java reasons while updating it.